# Warning shows when i use Hash Map In android(Use new SparseArray<String>)

Tags: android, hashmap

I am new to developing in android. In my android app I'm using `HashMap`, but I'm getting a warning:

```
**"Use new SparseArray<String>(...) instead for better performance"**
```

What does this mean, and how can I use `SparseArray<String>` instead?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

> Use new `SparseArray<String>(...)` instead for better performance

You are getting this warning because of reason described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html).

> SparseArrays map integers to Objects. Unlike a normal array of
>   Objects, there can be gaps in the indices. It is intended to be more
>   efficient than using a HashMap to map Integers to Objects.

Now

> how i use SparseArray ?

You can do it by below ways:

1. `HashMap` way:

   ```
   Map<Integer, Bitmap> _bitmapCache = new HashMap<Integer, Bitmap>();
   private void fillBitmapCache() {
        _bitmapCache.put(R.drawable.icon, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon));
        _bitmapCache.put(R.drawable.abstrakt, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.abstrakt));
        _bitmapCache.put(R.drawable.wallpaper, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wallpaper));
        _bitmapCache.put(R.drawable.scissors, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
    }

   Bitmap bm = _bitmapCache.get(R.drawable.icon);
   ```
2. `SparseArray` way:

   ```
   SparseArray<Bitmap> _bitmapCache = new SparseArray<Bitmap>();
   private void fillBitmapCache() {
        _bitmapCache.put(R.drawable.icon, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon));
        _bitmapCache.put(R.drawable.abstrakt, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.abstrakt));
        _bitmapCache.put(R.drawable.wallpaper, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wallpaper));
        _bitmapCache.put(R.drawable.scissors, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
    }

   Bitmap bm = _bitmapCache.get(R.drawable.icon);
   ```

Hope it Will Help.

Comment: Make certain to see the linked documentation which goes on to detail that the "implementation is not intended to be appropriate for data structures that may contain large numbers of items." A SparseArray is generally slower than a comparable HashMap.

Comment: I'd read the docs, but still had some questions and read a bit about Java maps as well. Somethings I found on HashMap: It provides constant-time performance for get/put, IF the hash function disperses "properly". Map permits a null key (table does not). On sparse arrays, docs say better performance with small sets of data. What size? (quote) "For containers holding up to hundreds of items, the performance difference is less than 50%" -- I take that to mean sparse begin losing out to map(/table?) when working with hundreds of key:values. In my case - I wanted sparse.

Answer (score 42):

`SparseArray` is used when you are using an `Integer` as a key.

When using the `SparseArray`, the **key** will stay as a **primitive variable** at all times unlike when you use the `HashMap` where it is required to have a **`Object`** as a **key** which will cause the **int to become an `Integer` object** just for a short time while getting the object in the map.

By using the `SparseArray` you will save the **Garbage Collector** some work.

So use just like a `Map<Integer,String>`.

Comment: +1, avoids the autoboxing (and associated objects+GC) that happens with HashMap. @cyril-mottier wrote about it here: https://speakerdeck.com/cyrilmottier/optimizing-android-ui-pro-tips-for-creating-smooth-and-responsive-apps

Comment: Technically you are **not** "using an `Integer` as a key". You are using an `int`.

Answer (score 5):

It's a hint that there is a better data structure for your code.

That hint is from Lint. You usually get it when you have a `HashMap` of integers to something else.

Its biggest advantage is to treat the integer key as a primitive. In other words, it won't covert to an `Integer` (the Java object) to use it as a key.

This is a big deal when using large maps. `HashMap` will result in the creation of many, many `Integer` objects in that case.

See a few more pieces of information [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/G-ceop4xp48).

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html says: " The implementation is not intended to be appropriate for data structures that may contain large numbers of items. It is generally slower than a traditional HashMap, ..." - that means: if you are interested in speed and want to store many values you have to use HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

SparseArray is better memory efficient Data Structure than HashMap for integer key value pairs. And it is specific to Android and I believe it can't be used for Java SE.

Sometimes, Linter warning shows that SparseArray must be used as in the above. This dumb warning might be right or wrong. You need to decide to use SparseArray rather HashMap if you find it suitable or you need to suppress it with @SuppressLint annotation.

To decide whether to implement, it is worthwhile doing a little research and evaluate your situation. You can find all some useful links here

https://gunhansancar.com/sparsearray-vs-hashmap/

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray